# How to use filter domains with jenkins email-ext plugin?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, email-ext

Currently my Jenkins instance sends emails to committers (in case of failing builds).
I wish to use the email-ext plugin and write a groovy script that will only send an email in case the commit belongs to a specific domain which I want to define.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a Default Pre-send script like:

```
recipients = msg.getRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO)
filtered = recipients.findAll { addr -> addr.toString().contains('@gooddomain.com') }
msg.setRecipients(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, filtered as javax.mail.Address[])
```

From: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+Recipes

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a pre-send script. It gives you complete access to the MimeMessage object, so you could iterate through the list of people in the To and if the domain you don't want exists in the list, you can set cancel = True

Answer (score 0):

normally Jenkins use email from people's configuration (Jenkings -> People -> configure).
If you don't want to send an email to some people just remove email address.